# Data structure to find if one string is a prefix of another

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures

This is an interview question: Design a data structure to perform the following operation efficiently: `boolean isPrefix(String s1, String s2)`.

I guess we can create a `multimap`, which maps prefixes to their strings. For instance,

```
strings: "aa", "ab", "abc", "ba", "ca"
multimap: "a"   -> ["aa", "ab", "abc"]
          "aa"  -> ["aa"]
          "ab"  -> ["ab", "abc"]
          "abc" -> ["abc"]
          "ba"  -> ["ba"]
          "ca"  -> ["ca"]
```

Which data structure would you propose ?

Comment: Why not using a trie? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: i am not sure if i understand what you mean by "efficiently". The problem has a time complexity of o(n) - your proposed solution is trading it for a space complexity of o(exp(n)) to get a time complexity of o(n) again for e.g. lookup of "a" and searhcing S2 in the resulting list?

Comment: Is your actual problem like follows? You have a whole bunch of strings and you want to do some kind of preprocessing on these strings such that consecutive calls to `isPrefix` are *very* fast. Because the problem - as you stated it - is solvable by just comparing the two strings `s1` and `s2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trie data structure would seem like an obvious answer, but the problem as stated doesn't require an advanced data structure.  A simple string comparison will suffice and would be very fast.  Ultimately, if you want to validate that one string is a prefix of another, you will have to compare every character at corresponding positions.  No data structure eliminates the need for the character-by-character comparison.

That being said, if you're *searching* for the prefix in a large body of text, there are other techniques such as [Rabin-Karp probablistic string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The most effective storage for prefix information is probably the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

In this, the strings correspond to nodes in a tree where one string has another as a prefix exactly when its node is below the other in the tree.